# What is the right way to create recursive dynamic expanding nav in angular, and how to toggle its menu item properly?

Tags: html, css, angular, recursion

I have an Angular 8 app I'm working on. I'm using boostrap 4 layout in my application. What I have created yet is a menu which having some nested menu items. I'm following [Dynamic Expanding Nav Drawer](https://stackblitz.com/edit/dynamic-nested-sidenav-menu) example to create a dynamic expanding navbar.

The issue which I'm facing is when I click on my (1st Level / Parent) menu item it expands all nested menu items, which I want to prevent.

Below code I've tried:

```
<div class="row">
  <div *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenu; context:{ $implicit: navItems }"></div>
  <ng-template #recursiveMenu let-menus>
    <ul class="w-100">
      <li *ngFor="let menu of menus;">
        <a class="align-self-stretch text-left" href="#" title="{{menu.displayName}}" (click)="onItemSelected(menu)">
          <i class="fa {{menu.iconName}}"></i> <span class="nav-header-primary p-2">{{menu.displayName}}</span> &nbsp;
          <span *ngIf="menu.children" class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x pull-right" [@indicatorRotate]="expanded ? 'expanded': 'collapsed'">
          </span>
        </a>
        <ul *ngIf="menu.children && expanded" id="nav{{menu.id}}">
          <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenu; context:{ $implicit: menu.children }"></ng-container>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>
  </ng-template>
</div>
```

Kindly helpHere is a code [stackblitz output](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-gymqtj). Let me know where I'm doing wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

All you sub menu items are getting expanded when you expand parent item, as you are maintaining a common/single flag for checking whether the menu is in expanded state or not.
So when you expand a parent item the expanded flag is set to true and all your menu items are also getting expanded. 
so instead of maintaining a common flag you can maintain a flag for each item, in map.
You can add a id property in your menu list:

```
navItems: INavItem[] = [
    {
      id: 1,
      displayName: 'Home',
      iconName: 'fa-home fa-lg p-2',
      route: 'home'
    },
    {
      displayName: 'Settings',
      id: 2,
      iconName: 'fa-cog',
      children: [
        {
          displayName: 'Navigation Management',
          iconName: 'fa-sliders',
          id: 3,
          children: [
            {
              displayName: 'Navigation & Form Mapping',
              id: 4,
              iconName: 'fa-handshake-o',
              route: 'navigation-form-mapping'
            }]
    }]
}]
```

You can maintain use expanded as a map of key-value pairs, in update your onItemSelected function as:

```
onItemSelected(item: INavItem) {
    if (item.children && item.children.length) {
      this.expanded[item.id] = !this.expanded[item.id];
    }
}
```

And your html can be updated as:

```
 <span *ngIf="menu.children" class="fa fa-caret-down fa-2x pull-right" [@indicatorRotate]="expanded[menu.id] ? 'expanded': 'collapsed'">
 </span>
 <ul *ngIf="menu.children && expanded[menu.id]" id="nav{{menu.id}}">
      <ng-container *ngTemplateOutlet="recursiveMenu; context:{ $implicit: menu.children }"></ng-container>
 </ul>
```

[Working Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-r8wsr5)

Comment: Great men, how can I forget this.